# Проблема при динамическом отображении меню

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar

У меня есть Activity в которой есть TabLayout c 3-мя фрагментами. При переключении на новый фрагмент, мне нужно обновлять меню для моего ToolBar. Меню обновляется но не с первого раза. Сначала нужно пару раз по вкладкам по переходить, что бы потом меню обновилось. Не нашел информации об этом в гугле.

вот как я обновляю меню:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fm_fragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` вызываете при создании фрагмента? `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)` вызывать в этом методе не нужно.

Comment: setHasOptionsMenu(true) вызываю

Comment: Попытался сделать иначе, через setVisible(), но результат тот же. При переходе на фрагмент меню появляется не с первого раза, да еще и с задержкой

Comment: вы пробовали убрать вызов super-метода в конце?

Comment: Да, везде убрал, не работает. Еще, возможно поможет эта информация. У меня TabLayout связан с ViewPager

Comment: Проблема где то в другом месте. В методе создания меню все правильно. Нужно больше информации (кода, связанного с проблемой)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54360/discussion-between--and-pavlofff).